# How to solve $\int \tan^2(x) \sec (x) \ dx$?

Tags: integration

How should one solve the following integral? $$\int \tan^2(x) \sec (x) \ dx$$

I can't think of any substitutions to be made involving $\tan^2(x)=\sec^2 (x)-1$ or $\sec^2(x)=\tan^2(x)+1$, which is how I've been solving most of the similar problems in my book until now. What should I do?

Comment: Try to make substitution.

Comment: @Asker, what about integration by parts? Would it work?

Comment: @science When I substitute $u= \sec x$ then I end up with $\int \sqrt {u^2-1} \ du$, which I'm not sure how to integrate.

Comment: @Artem I thought of integrating by parts, but I stupidly missed the right parts! After giving it another try with the right ones, it worked out well- thanks!

Comment: Did you try searching ("integral tan sec", for example)? This was asked earlier *today*...

Comment: @HansLundmark My bad- I did try a search, but I guess my parameters were too specific to find the previously asked question. I searched something like $\int tan^2x secx \ dx$ and looked through some of the suggested questions but did not see anything. Will try a more general search next time like the one you suggested

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only by doing this in two harder ways did I catch a really nice trick for this problem in particular.

By doing $\tan^2(x)=\sec^2(x)-1$ we get

$$\int \sec(x) \tan^2(x) dx = \int \sec^3(x) dx - \int \sec(x) dx.$$

On the other hand, by integrating by parts with $dv=\sec(x) \tan(x) dx$ and $u=\tan(x)$, we get

$$\int \sec(x) \tan^2(x) dx = \sec(x) \tan(x) - \int \sec^3(x) dx.$$

Adding these equations we get:

$$2 \int \sec(x) \tan^2(x) dx = \sec(x) \tan(x) - \int \sec(x) dx.$$

So you just have to compute the last integral, which I will leave to you.

Comment: +1 for adding the equations like that- fantastic solution.

Answer (score 1):

To build on Ian's answer, you may find it easier to integrate $2\sec^3(x)dx$ instead of just $\sec^3(x)dx$.

Hint as to why this might be easier: $\sec x\tan^2x$

Comment: I think this answer would be more appropriate as a comment to Ian's answer.

Comment: unfortunately, I do not have enough reputation to comment on the posts of others.

Comment: Ah, that's a pity. I didn't remember that.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of sine and cosine you have
$$
\int \frac{\sin^2x}{\cos^3x}\,dx=
\int\frac{\sin^2x}{(1-\sin^2x)^2}\cos x\,dx
$$
With the substitution $t=\sin x$ the integral becomes (after splitting into partial fractions)
$$
\int\frac{t^2}{(1-t^2)^2}\,dt
=
\frac{1}{4}\int\left(
  \frac{1}{t-1}+\frac{1}{(t-1)^2}-\frac{1}{t+1}+\frac{1}{(t+1)^2}
\right)\,dt
$$
which is elementary.